# C# prevent default action on a listbox control when the right or left arrow keys are pressed

Tags: c#, events, listbox, keyboard

I have a listbox control in a windows app and I want to disable the default right and left arrow keydown event triggers.  Currently when you press right or left arrows the selected item travels up and down the listbox.  I want to add my own actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding an event handler to the `ListBox.KeyDown` event. If the key pressed is an arrow key, set the `Handled` flag of the `KeyPressEventArgs` to `true` to prevent further processing.

A code example, based on an [MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/61a6c539-d3f2-4f85-89ab-278d29c99487/)

```
private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  If (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I believe that since these keys are considered System Key bindings, this will not work. I think you must use `ProcessCmdKey`

Comment: Yeah the default event action still occurs after the KeyDown method processes. I'll look into the processCmdKey method.

Comment: @Paul: Do you set the `Handled` flag to `true` to prevent further processing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) method in the listbox control. Create a new class, derive it from listbox, then override the ProcessCmdKey.